# Data type still shows 'Object' even after using pandas datetime conversion?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with COVID19 data and have a date column. It was originally as Int64, so I changed it to datetime object using the below function:

```
us['date'] = pd.to_datetime(us['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
us['date'] = us['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%d")
```

When I print out the result, I see all the data in the column as "1/1, 1/4, 2/1 ....", so on. (There is no null value here) I'm trying to use group this by month, so I tried to use another function to get only months as below:

```
us['date'].dt.strftime("%m")
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I don't understand, since I change the datatype to datetime using pd_datetime, should this column already be datetime, not object? When I checked the data type, it shows 'O'. Why is this so?

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: Try posting some sample data covering all formats of us['date'] prior any manipulation.

Comment: "*It was originally as Int64*" - then parsing with `format='%Y%m%d'` doesn't make much sense to me - instead, this should require you to supply a unit, e.g. `unit='s'` if the datetime data is represented as UNIX time / seconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 1):

When we do ignore ,it will `ignore` the whole column if any item can not be changed ,we should do `coerce`

```
us['date'] = pd.to_datetime(us['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
us['date'].dt.strftime('%B')
```

Comment: Hi, I still get the exact same attribute error.......

Comment: @sarahkim let us drop na value ~

Comment: Yes I changed to coerce and tried, same error. pd.to_datetime worked perfectly fine. I changed from 20200101 string --> 2020-01-01 datetime successfully. From here I tried to extract the month 2020-01-01 --> January, is where I'm failing...

Comment: @sarahkim `us['date'].dt.strftime('%B')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

```
us['monthanddate'] = us['date'].dt.strftime("%m/%d")
```

For only month

```
us['monthonly'] = us['date'].dt.strftime("%m")
```